# Ubuntu (64 bit): installing java SDK

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, java, sdk

I need to install java (j2se sdk) on my computer for running a program (SQLDeveloper).  All the write ups talk about installing the FireFox plug-in.

What do I have to do to get this installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the partner source (assuming you're using Lucid):

```
sudo add-apt-repository “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner”
```

Update, and then install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

Comment: Ok, I did this.  Where does it install it?  I need to point SQLDeveloper to the folder where the installation lives.

Comment: I see java in /usr/bin, but when I use this, SQLDeveloper tells me this is just the JRE not SDK.

Comment: This should install to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20

Answer (score 1):

This is Sun's link to download the SDK:
http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp

you may need to set your $JAVA_HOME environmental variable afterwards.

For example:

```
% export JAVA_HOME=<the path where you installed the JDK>
```

You'll want to set this in your .profile to avoid manually setting it each session.

I'm not familiar with the SQLDeveloer installer, but it may make it easier for you by allowing you to specify the JDK location.

GL